# Can an Android device be damaged if I use it to deploy apps on it using Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment, xamarin.android, device

I want to develop Android apps using Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin. The emulator for Android doesn't work on my laptop beacause of a driver conflict.

I have an Android device that runs Android 6.0 Marshmallow, I've set it up and I've managed to deploy a simple app on it. I am planning to develop more complex apps on Android using Xamarin and I want to use my device instead of the emulator.

I want to know if there is a possibility of **damaging** my device by using it to deploy apps **instead** of using the emulator (it is my personal phone and I don't want to lose data or make it unusable).

Thank you

Comment: I think no. If you don't have root permission, you can't damage anything.

Comment: So any app that I deploy on the device can't access my data (phone numbers, pictures, etc.) even if it uses communication over Internet?

Comment: No. For access your data you have to add permission in AndroidManifest. Without this permissions, app can't access your data.

Comment: Deploying is just a fancy word for installing

Comment: @TimCastelijns: correct, but when you develop an app, you have to deploy (install) it many times on the device and I don't know if this may be harmful in some way.

Comment: Every app developer installs apps a hundred times or more during development. That's what the system is for.

Comment: `So any app that I deploy on the device can't access my data`. Strange question. If you are the app developer you will know what the app does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to damage hardware from software, so I can say that this part is impossible. (just want to cover everything)

I don't think it is possible to damage the OS, or any other apps, using another app. This is because all the apps are sandboxed: 
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html

> The Android Application Sandbox, which isolates your app data and code execution from other apps.

Finally, I don't think you can even damage your own app. Sure, you could go and delete files, but those would have been the ones that you created. You cannot accidentally delete the apk (or the files within) from your app as they do not live in an area you can access.

As @Andrea said: you also need to ask for explicitly permission to do many (most) things. You can't get the photos unless you announce to Android that you want to access them - and then it will let you know first. The internet is out of bounds, until you ask Android first:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Permissions

> Because Android sandboxes applications from each other, applications must explicitly share resources and data. They do this by declaring the permissions they need for additional capabilities not provided by the basic sandbox, including access to device features such as the camera.

As I am a developer, and I have deployed apps thousands (maybe millions) of times to a device (I mostly use a device), I have not noticed any issues. And, if anything does (for some impossible reason) wrong, you can always reset the device to factory settings.

I will note: if you root your device (run as a system user), you may cause issues if you start fiddling around. But this is not what you (or any general consumer) should or would do. It is like logging into a system as an administrator and deleting the system files. Nobody does that and expects it to still work.